# What does "qualify as a moonshot" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used this link but it didn't help me get what the writer meant. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159638/what-does-moonshots-mean

""You do realize that at Google that is what we qualify as a moonshot?" Deane remembers the Google team asking her when they heard her story."

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/05/13/this-mom-built-a-65-million-business-the-cambridge-satchel-company.html

Comment: "achievement on a grand scale".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: Does it mean "Do you think that when invited by Google it means that you have made an achievement on a grand scale"?

Comment: So your question is not about **moonshot** but about the antecedent of **that** in "that is what we qualify as a moonshot"?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: No, I didn't understand the whole sentence.

Comment: "That is something we consider an achievement on a grand scale".

Comment: While I agree that her achievement had been on a grand scale, I'm more inclined to agree with J.R. Bob Dobbs's answer that the Google team had meant, "You do realize that at Google that is what we qualify as a(n extremely) risky move [sacrificing everything without knowing if it would succeed or not]?" Perhaps a combination of both definitions?

Comment: In the meantime, here is a tech page that actually purports to say exactly what Google would call moonshots: http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/moonshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Moonshot" is an idiom that typically means that something is a longshot, or very difficult to achieve.  I think that in the context that you present, it means an investment in something that succeeds and pays off beyond all expectations.